# (Not 1) evaluates to -2 for some reason

Tags: vba, operators, bitwise-operators, bitwise-not

Why does (Not 1) evaluate as -2?  I would expect it to evaluate as 0.

[image]

Comment: Two's complement? In (8-bit) binary, 1 is `00000001` and -2 is `11111110`, you're doing a bitwise not.

Comment: So how do I stop doing a bitwise not?  InStr returns a position in a string and I need to take action if a string is not found, ie If Not InStr....

Comment: Well what value *do* you get if it's not found? Check for that.

Comment: InStr returns some index greater than 0 if found, and applying Not makes the value -2.  Thus because the value is -2 and not 0, my if statement doesn't work

Comment: And *what does it return if not found?!* Maybe check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA/VBScript does not have real logical operators (AND, OR, NOT). The logical operators you see are actually bitwise operators, and that's all you get. VBA plays some games with the `True` and `False` values so this works most of the time, but occasionally you'll find a "gotcha".

In this case, instead of `If Not InStr() Then` you have to write `If InStr() <= 0 Then`.
Instead of `If InStr() Then` you have to write `If InStr() > 0 Then`

In other words: `InStr()` returns a **number**. Don't try to treat it like a boolean.

Comment: Good, concise answer - the last sentence is key.

Answer (score 5):

`1` is not the integer representation of `True`, `-1` is.

```
Debug.Print CInt(True) 'prints -1
Debug.Print CInt(False) 'prints 0
```

Boolean operators (`Not`, `And`, `Or`, `XOr`) behave as "logical operators" when their operands are Boolean values. When they're not, they behave as "bitwise operators" but the truth is, they're *always* bitwise.

The integer value `1` converts to the Boolean value `True` only because `True` is defined as `Not False`, which means *any* non-zero value is a Boolean `True`. But you only get the correct/expected logical behavior when you use `-1` for `True`.

An `Integer` is represented by 16 bits, so `1` is this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0001
```

This makes `Not 1` this:

```
1111 1111 1111 1110
```

The sign bit is on, so the value is negative - trim the insignificant digits and you get:

```
10
```

Which is the binary representation for `2`. Hence, `Not 1` is `-2`.

Inversely, `-1` would be:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111
```

And `Not -1` is thus:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have already explained about the *why*, I want to focus on the coding practices.

As you found out, `Not x` is not necessarily what you want. In practice you want more like `Not CBool(x)`. However, `CBool()` can throw errors - for example, `CBool(Null)` yields error 91 (invalid use of null).

It might be claimed that you can avoid this by strong-typing your variables but even not using a `Variant` does not guarantee that in an expression a `Boolean` will stay a `Boolean`. Example:

```
?typename(true and 0)
Integer
```

In practice, it's too easy to accidentally allow VBA to do the voodoo implicit conversions for you, so for that reasons, altering coding habits might suit you better.

For testing truthy values, you want expressions like:

`If x Then`

And for falsy values, you want expressions like:

`If x = False Then`

Those works regardless of the type of the `x`, whether it's an expression or not and thus is said to be much more consistent/predictable in its behavior compared to the `If x = True Then` or `If Not x Then`. By adopting this code habit, you can help avoid creating subtle bugs arising from accidental conversion away from `Boolean` types and getting a bitwise operation rather than logical operation.

For assignments, using a `Boolean` variable will work in ensuring that it's consistently coerced into either `True` or `False` and not some random numbers.